# How to direct https requests to http while SSL cert expired?

Tags: redirects, https, security-certificate

The `SSL` certificate on my site has expired, which has caused `https` requests to the site to fail.

While I am sorting out a new `SSL` certificate, what can I do to redirect `https` requests into the `http` requests?

The `https` folder of my site is sym-linked to the `http` folder.

Comment: OMG i just come to this forum for the first time to ask almost same question and it happened that it's in last few questions :D

Answer (score 0):

If you have Apache and mod_rewrite, then put this script in a .htaccess file that needs to be in your root folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: I am using a commercial web-host.  How can I tell if `mod_rewrite` is on?

Comment: Use this code in a php script 

in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules());

Comment: Commenting the redirect/rewrite code will serve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You would have added http to http redirect in your .htaccess file or your .conf file.

Open the file where the redirect has been added and comment the redirect/rewrite code.

Your website will start to resolve using http:// protocol.